# Recursive components in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I using vue components to display comments as well as replies to the comments. To display the replies I am simply using comment component recursively. however, I am getting an error.

Here's my code

```
<template>
    <div class="box">
        <article class="media">
            <figure class="media-left">
                <p class="image is-64x64">
                    <img :src="comment.channel.data.imageUrl">
                </p>
            </figure>
            <div class="media-content">
                <div class="content">
                    <p>
                        <strong><a :href="channelUrl">{{ comment.channel.data.name }}</a></strong> <small>{{ comment.created_at_human }}</small>
                        <br>
                        <p class="is-medium">{{ comment.body }}</p>
                        <nav class="level is-mobile">
                            <div class="level-left">
                                <a class="level-item">
                                    <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i></span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
       <comment v-for="reply in comment.replies.data" :comment="reply" :key="reply.id"></comment>
</div>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

found in

---> <Reply> at /home/vagrant/Laravel/youtube/resources/assets/js/components/Comment.vue... (1 recursive calls)
       <VideoComments> at /home/vagrant/Laravel/youtube/resources/assets/js/components/VideoComments.vue
         <VideoPlayerLayout> at /home/vagrant/Laravel/youtube/resources/assets/js/components/VideoPlayerLayout.vue
           <Root>
```

Data is available in the object as I am using fractal to generate json output. Don't really know where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three places in the template where you are referencing a data property that is a third tier nested property, `comment.channel.data.imageUrl`, `comment.replies.data`, and `comment.channel.data.name`.

If at *any* time, `comment.channel` or `comment.replies` is `undefined`, you will see this error.

For the replies you could guard it this way:

```
<template v-if="comment.replies">
  <comment v-for="reply in comment.replies.data" :comment="reply" :key="reply.id"></comment>
</template>
```

For `comment.channel.data.name` you could use

```
{{comment.channel && comment.channel.data && comment.channel.data.name }}
```

For `comment.channel.data.imageUrl` you could use

```
<p v-if="comment.channel && comment.channel.data" class="image is-64x64">
  <img :src="comment.channel.data.imageUrl">
</p>
```